# Class taking ownership of a std::vector by move

Tags: c++, move-semantics

Say I want to take ownership of a `std::vector` but potentially it does not contains all the data. I know the final size from the beginning. How can I process to move construct the parameter in my class

```
struct MyMetierStuff {
//....

std::vector<int> buf;

//constructor taking parameter by rvalue refence.
//final size is maybe bigger than data.size()

MyMetierStuff(std::vector<int>&& data, size_t final_size) :
buf(std::move(data)
{
 //suboptimal, as reallocation may happen..
 buf.resize(final_size);  

}
```

Is there a more optimized way ? maybe not moving it when size does not match as reallocation is inevitable ?

Comment: This is about the best you can do if you really want to ensure the vector is the proper size upon construction time. If you relax that constraint, maybe you can do better.

Comment: If you know the final size from the beginning, why not create the vector with that size?

Comment: If you know the intended final size from the beginning and want to avoid a reallocation you can use the `reserve` member function which `std::vector` provides specifically for this purpose.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux calling `reserve` instead of `resize` here will not prevent reallcation. Or did you mean the caller will reserve in `data` before constructing a `MyMetierStuff` object ?

Comment: Resizing a `std::vector` may trigger a reallocation, that is correct.  It is not clear to me how "class taking ownership" of the vector has any bearing on that.  This question seems to be asking what to do when a vector's size is too small.

Comment: @wohlstad I mean that you could call `reserve` when you initialize the vector you intend to pass to `MyMetierStuff`. When you wrote "I know the final size from the beginning." I assumed that meant before anything relevant to the question, including initializing the vector that would be provided as the constructor argument. There is nothing you can do locally in the constructor body.

Comment: If `data.size() == final_size` is true, you can just `move()` the `data` as-is into `buf`. Otherwise, if `data.size() < final_size` is true then you can't avoid an allocation on `buf`. But what you can do is `reserve()`/`resize()` the `buf` to `final_size` up front, and then `move()` each `data` element into `buf` and clear `data`'s memory.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the vector is cheap and will copy just the data pointer, size and capacity, so 24 bytes in a normal implementation. Then when you resize (or reserve) the `final_size` there is no choice but to copy the data if `final_size > capacity`.

Now you could initialize the vector to an empty vector and then check for `final_size > data.capacity()`. If it's larger then reserve the space and move the data into the new vector object by object. Otherwise you can move data as a whole using the move assignment operator.

But really what would that save? You still copy/move the exact same number of objects in every case. You might save copying 24 byte in one case at the cost of copying an extra 24 bytes in the other. You would have to look at the implementation of your vector and go through both sources step by step and count where the data pointer, size and capacity is initialized, overwritten or swapped for both implementations.

I assume those 24 bytes are irrelevant compared to the amount of data in the vector or you wouldn't be worried about moving the data. And writing it like you have is just so much simpler than implementing what amounts to the same manually.

Comment: Indeed I am realizing that I have misunderstand move constructor of a std::vector. I though that allocated memory will simply be stolen from other.. basically I expected in the happy case where no resizing is needed that no allocation at all will occurs.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve my goal ?

Comment: You already achieved your goal. If `final_size <= capacity` no memory will be allocated and not objects will be moved. That's exactly what your code does.